# Framework7 Vue Cordova image reference

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

I just started with Framework7 Vue starter kit and wasnt sure how the images worked. There is a folder for images under `src/assets/static/images` and in their docs it says to put images for the project there. My question is in a vue file how do I reference them? In the www project folder I dont see any images in put in the `src/assets/static/images` being transferred anywhere when I do a build?

Answer (score 0):

Path to static assets should be configured in config/index.js file  with the below code

```
// config/index.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  build: {
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static'
  }
}
```

then you can include image in your page with

```
<img src="/static/imagename.png"></img>
```

below detailed reference on how framework7 + vue handle static assets
https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html